# Error in request of client ws-security soap with wss4j and cxf

Tags: java, soap, cxf, ws-security, wss4j

I made the changes you told me "pedrofb" and the exception change , I was wrongly calling the output exept of the request (cxfEndpoint.getInInterceptors (). Add (new PropertiesWSS4JOutInterceptor (outProps, cryto)), when it is really cxfEndpoint.getOutInterceptors () .add (new PropertiesWSS4JOutInterceptor (outProps, cryto)). Use the "cxfEndpoint.getOutInterceptors (). Add (new LoggingOutInterceptor ())" as you told me but it does not get to log anything in console. But the errors persist, now it gives me another exception:

```
oct 17, 2017 5:06:14 PM org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean buildServiceFromClass
INFORMACIÓN: Creating Service {DGI_Modernizacion_Consolidado}WSPersonaGetActEmpresarialSoapPortService from class dgi_modernizacion_consolidado.WSPersonaGetActEmpresarialSoapPort
oct 17, 2017 5:06:17 PM org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain add
ADVERTENCIA: Skipping interceptor org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJInInterceptor$SAAJPreInInterceptor: Phase read specified does not exist.
oct 17, 2017 5:06:18 PM org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor checkActions
ADVERTENCIA: Security processing failed (actions mismatch)
oct 17, 2017 5:06:18 PM org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor handleMessage
ADVERTENCIA: 
org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: An error was discovered processing the <wsse:Security> header
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.checkActions(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:361)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:317)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:271)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:530)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:463)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:366)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:319)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:133)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.execute(Unknown Source)
    at t2voice.dgi.client_dgi.App.main(App.java:201)
```

I have had many changes and that is why I have confused you, sorry, please forgive me. This is the code corresponding to new error. What I can be doing wrong?

```
JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
factory.setServiceClass(WSPersonaGetActEmpresarialSoapPort.class);
factory.setAddress("https://server.info.digitalsound.gub:6000/ePrueba/ws_personaGetActEmpresarialPrueba?wsdl");

WSPersonaGetActEmpresarialSoapPort port = (WSPersonaGetActEmpresarialSoapPort) factory.create();
org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);            
Endpoint cxfEndpoint = client.getEndpoint();
Map<String, Object> outProps = new HashMap<String, Object>();
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, WSHandlerConstants.SIGNATURE);   
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.USER, "alias"); 
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIG_PROP_FILE, "ws.properties");
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIG_KEY_ID, "DirectReference");
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PASSWORD_TYPE, WSConstants.PW_TEXT);
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_CLASS,ClientPasswordCallback.class.getName());
Map<String, Object> inProps = new HashMap<String, Object>();
inProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, WSHandlerConstants.SIGNATURE);
inProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.USER, "alias");
inProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIG_PROP_FILE, "ws.properties");
inProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIG_KEY_ID, "DirectReference");
cxfEndpoint.getInInterceptors().add(new PropertiesWSS4JInInterceptor(inProps, cryto));
cxfEndpoint.getOutInterceptors().add(new PropertiesWSS4JOutInterceptor(outProps, cryto));
WSPersonaGetActEmpresarialExecute parameters = new WSPersonaGetActEmpresarialExecute();
parameters.setRut("43557783445");
WSPersonaGetActEmpresarialExecuteResponse resp = port.execute(parameters);
```

and this is the corresponding ws.properties

```
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider=org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias=alias
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type = PKCS12
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password=keystore_pass
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.file=keystore.pfx
```

Comment: You need to include the SSL server certificate in the truststore used by wss4j. Create a JKS and include it there. Then configure `${PREFIX}.merlin.truststore .*` properties as shown here:https://ws.apache.org/wss4j/config.html

Comment: I did exactly that and it still gives me the same error, ie create two keystore, one to enter the private key and another the public key, and put them in the different entries of the properties file merlin.

Comment: This is my properties file:

Comment: org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider=org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias=example
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type=JKS
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password=mykeystore
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.file=mykeystore.jks
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.truststore.file=truststore2.jks
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.truststore.password=truststore2
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.truststore.type=JKS

Comment: The properties in comment and in your question are different. You re signing the soap.and sending user/password. Could you post a sample SOAP.request generated with SoapUI and with your code?

Comment: Hello pedrofb , here I leave an example of the request that is built with Soap UI, it is simple, I have made many modifications in the file .properties, my doubt is that I need besides the .pfx file that is the original and the password of this one. So I need something more to consume the soap service with wss, and if possible know if the .properties are badly formed, because I suspect something is wrongly configured and that's why wss4j returns that error

Comment: <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:edu="Modernizacion" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">

Comment: <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="X509-4A55C50E37934CA42815081728266561">

Comment: ZCj4eG9Pere</wsse:BinarySecurityToken><ds:Signature Id="SIG-4A55C50E37934CA42815081728267505" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="edu soapenv" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:CanonicalizationMethod><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>

Comment: <ds:DigestValue>ZCj4eG9PereyG7Niu7avDM+nzWCz4Yu3PoirGKnq23rKkCGeObcqby2xkh7JN2PzcjAIbXTA20w9KUBRkk=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue>2kLG+BQgsDDYWpeAz</ds:SignatureValue>

Comment: <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-4A55C50E37934CA42815081728267012"><wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-4A55C50E37934CA42815081728267153"><wsse:Reference URI="#X509-4A55C50E37934CA42815081728266561" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/></wsse:SecurityTokenReference></ds:KeyInfo></ds:Signature></wsse:Security></soapenv:Header>

Comment: <soapenv:Body wsu:Id="id-4A55C50E37934CA42815081728267474" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
      <edu:WS_Empresarial.Execute>
         <edu:Inf>78966544</edu:Inf>
      </edu:WS_Empresarial.Execute>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: Please, do not post code or examples in comments. It is difficult to read. Just edit your own question and  include the relevant parts